# How do I require a package installed via .cask in a project

Tags: require, cask

I'm trying to contrib to a project and installed cask and did `cask install` and now I have a .cask folder with the deps.  Now in emacs how do I evaluate a .`require` of one of those deps?  Is there a linking step that must be done to point the resolution to the .cask folder?

Comment: If the package has its dependencies properly declared,`cask install` should do all the setup that is necessary.  Cask then builds the `load-path` automatically for you so that `(require ...)` statements resolve when you invoke `cask exec`.  You may need to further illustrate your circumstances, to clarify how things are not as you expect.  Are you interactively working on the package within emacs?  You might try starting emacs using `cask emacs` from within the package directory to have the desired load-path or reading though https://github.com/cask/cask/issues/360.

Comment: So in my case I cloned the cider project https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider.  
Downloaded and ran `cask install` and I see the .cask folder.  I open up the test and try to eval the `(require 'buttercup)` expression and it just says `cannot open load file: no such file or directory, buttercup`.  This is mainly so I can develop with the proper indentation as that is attached to the defs of buttercup.  Otherwise the indentation is the standard lisp for function calls which aligns arguments.

Comment: My workflow for package development is to independently install all package dependencies like that using `package-install` (ex: `M-x package-install buttercup`).  You will probably discover though that buttercup is not written with an interactive use of buttercup in mind.  I would recommend using `cask exec` (ex: `cask exec buttercup -L .`) to invoke buttercup so you can be confident that dependencies for your tests are properly expressed for cask.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with cask emacs and will look at  flycheck-cask.

Comment: How do i mark your answer as the appropriate one @ebpa , can't seem to do that with comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the package has its dependencies properly declared,cask install should do all the setup that is necessary. Cask then builds the load-path automatically for you so that (require ...) statements resolve when you invoke cask exec.

Interactively evaluation / development of a package with cask-installed dependencies seems to be a shortcoming of Cask.  Four options that come to mind:

1. Not rely on the cask dependency management at all during your interactive development and install the dependencies manually via `package-install` or your favorite package management tool.  Be sure to run your tests in an isolated environment using `cask exec` though.
2. Have cask build your load-path at startup and invoke `cask emacs` from inside the target package directory.
3. Adjust your load path to include the target package's dependencies under `.cask`.
4. Write a helper to inspect target package dependencies and install them using `package-install` or your favorite package management tool.